# Add icon to <th> in the HTML table

Tags: html

How do I add an icon as an image inside the  in the table?

```
<th class="px-1 py-2 font-medium text-jibuttonBlue text-left">
      <div class="">
        Date
        <img src="{{MEDIA_UI}}/icon-filter-table-column-selected.svg" alt="">
      </div>


    </th>
```

But the console isnt even displaying that there is a div. Cant I add a div and img inside?

Comment: The div and the img tag should be there, maybe it's a caching problem?

Comment: Shift+Reload normally does the trick.

Comment: Press `Ctrl` + `F5` or try it out in a new browser, I also think it's a caching problem.

Comment: Are you sure this => `th` is inside a table ?

Comment: its inside the table, just added the part of the code where I want the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to give a min `width` and `height` to your `img` if its inside the `table` => `th` for it to able to display inside.

If an `img` is outside the `table` OR `th` then there is **no** need for height and width.

In addition, make sure your `th` inside the `table` element.

**Live Working Demo:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="generaltable boxaligncenter" id="outlinetable" cellpadding="1">
  <th class="px-1 py-2 font-medium text-jibuttonBlue text-left">
    <div class="">
      Date
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" height='18' width='18'>
    </div>
  </th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to remove curly bracket before and after MEDIA UI, Then it will work.

```html
<th class="px-1 py-2 font-medium text-jibuttonBlue text-left">
      <div class="">
        Date
        <img src="MEDIA_UI/icon-filter-table-column-selected.svg" alt="">
      </div>


    </th>
```

Comment: I think "MEDIA_UI" is not supposed to be the name of a folder here.

Comment: Thanks @DeniJuric for your suggestion but according to my knowledge link can not be use in that way so other option is folder name.

Comment: I think it's just supposed to be a placeholder :)

Comment: the curly brackets are from the framework were using. IT has to be there. Seems to be some other issue causing the image not being displayed.